# MemoryStream: why convert to byte after readByte

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

In [this example from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), you'll notice that after we read a byte from memory stream, it goes into an int which must then be converted to byte.  It stikes me as strange that a function like `.ReadByte()` doesn't return a byte in the first place.  Is there a reason why MS did it this way?

```
// Read the remaining bytes, byte by byte.
while(count < memStream.Length)
{
    byteArray[count++] =
        Convert.ToByte(memStream.ReadByte());
}
```

---

a thought occured to me.  Perhaps this comes down to usage.  Perhaps `ReadByte()` is often used to retrieve short lengths, which subsequents get consumed in the retrieve via length variety

```
int length=ms.ReadByte();
ms.Read(buf,0,lenth);
```

i.e. you can use the length without a cast.  Is this a good enough reason?

Comment: You should check `ToArray()` in case you want a byte array

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is not specific to Memory stream, rather it is because of the design of base class "Stream" and the reason for that is

**Return value:**

> The unsigned byte cast to an Int32, or -1 if at the end of the stream.

-1 cannot be represented using unsigned byte

Comment: and -1 only gets returned if there is a timeout based on ReadTimeout?

Comment: Nope , -1 is for End of stream, ex: You have reached EOF on a file stream

Comment: So basically a single value is used to represent 2 cases i.e a stream is read or EOS reached. Other way to implement was to return byte but in case of EOF throw exception, but that would have its own issues

Comment: I notice an AsyncBeginRead... but for ReadByte, does timeout occur as an event or an exception?

Comment: I guess timeout will happen as exception.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `ReadByte` If the read is successful then the current position within the stream is advanced by one byte. but its designed to return -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.

Now this would not be a valid value for `Byte` (its unsigned)

`ms.Read(buf,0,lenth);` here lenth is the number of bytes to read from the stream and what you get from `ReadByte` is first byte its not be used in the this fashion, something like

```
byte[] buff = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Read(buff , 0, buff .Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe they are converting with that from `int` to `byte` in a reallllllly nice way, since `ReadByte()` returns an int and their `byteArray` is of type `int[]`.